# Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'SPTAudioStreamingDelegate!' When setting up Spotify API

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, spotify

Trying to set up Spotify API and have come across an error that reads:
"Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'SPTAudioStreamingDelegate!'" In the function below.

Im very lost here, any help would be appreciated.

```
    func initializePlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
    if self.player == nil {
        self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
        self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
        self.player!.delegate = self
        try! player!.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
        self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `self`, your view controller, does not conform to the `SPTAudioStreamingDelegate` protocol.

https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/Protocols/SPTAudioStreamingDelegate.html

```
class MyViewController : SPTAudioStreamingDelegate {
    ...
}
```